# Regexp разбить текст до 78 символов и чтобы не разбивались переводом строки шаблоны

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

По [формату интернет сообщений](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1) в строке должно быть не более 78 символов не считая CRLF. В строке есть замена символов на 16-й формат со знаком равно вида "=3D", чтобы вставить переводы строк и не разбить эту конструкцию есть решение

```
$newline="=\r\n";
$string=preg_replace ( '/(.{73}[^=]{0,3})/', '$1'.$newline, $string);
```

Также в тексте есть шаблоны вида "##FIO##", ##IO##, ##EMAIL## которые тоже не должны разбиваться переводом строки "=\r\n"
Пробовал конструкцию такого вида, но не срабатывает эта часть ([^=]{0,3})

```
$string=preg_replace ( '/.{68}(?:(?!##.+?##)[^=]){0,9}\K/', "=\r\n", $string);
```

да и для проверки трёх последних символов не нужен такой диапазон от 0 до 9, но если его сделать от 0 до 3 - то не будут вмещаться шаблоны
Это обычный шаблон рассылки на HTML где нужно делать такие вставки.
Вот часть как это выглядит в БД

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:verdana;">Если вы хотите отписаться от рассылки, то нажмите <a href="https://mysite.com/unsubscribe.php?email=##email##" target="_blank">Отписаться</a></span></div>
<p>##fio##</p>
<p>##fi##</p>
<p>##io##</p>
<p>##imya##</p>
<p>##email##</p>
```

После замены символов будет выглядеть так

```
<div style=3d"text-align: center;"><span style=3d"font-family:verdana;">=c5=f1=eb=e8 =e2=fb =f5=ee=f2=e8=f2=e5 =ee=f2=ef=e8=f1=e0=f2=fc=f1=ff =ee=f2 =f0=e0=f1=f1=fb=eb=ea=e8, =f2=ee =ed=e0=e6=ec=e8=f2=e5 <a href=3d"https://mysite.com/unsubscribe.php?email=3d##email##" target=3d"_blank">=ce=f2=ef=e8=f1=e0=f2=fc=f1=ff</a></span></div>=0d=0a=0d=0a<p>##fio##</p>=0d=0a=0d=0a<p>##fi##</p>=0d=0a=0d=0a<p>##io##</p>=0d=0a=0d=0a<p>##imya##</p>=0d=0a=0d=0a<p>##email##</p>
```

Comment: А можете привести полный текст для примера?

Comment: @The art of being alive добавил примеры в вопрос

Comment: @ОлександрДавиденко а разве [это](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-regex/thread2548232.html) не подходит?

Comment: @Эдуард Да, всё работает, хоть я не понял почему. Я видимо неправильно понимаю эту конструкцию **[^=]){0,9}** Любой символ кроме равновстречается от нуля и до девяти раз.
Окончательный ответ
`код` $string=preg_replace ( '/.{68}(?:(?!##\w+##)[^=]){0,9}\K/', "=\r\n", $string);

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=preg_replace ( '/.{69}(?:(?!##\w+##)[^=]){0,9}\K/', "=\r\n", $string);
```